# why azure function has table referencing old data?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I have two azure functions

1. One gets a new record from table storage (readFunction)
2. Updates second updates table storage as processed (updateFunction)

both functions call into this following function:

```
     public static async Task UpdateMessage(CloudTable table, string partitionKey, string rowKey, JobUpdateStatus  updateToStatus)
        {
            TableOperation retrieve = TableOperation.Retrieve<MigrationFeatures>(partitionKey, rowKey);

            TableResult result = await table.ExecuteAsync(retrieve);

            MigrationFeatures newMigrationData = (MigrationFeatures)result.Result;

            if (result != null)
            {
                var entity = new DynamicTableEntity(newMigrationData.PartitionKey, newMigrationData.RowKey);
                entity.ETag = "*";
                entity.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
                entity.Properties.Add("JobStatus", new EntityProperty(updateToStatus.ToString()));
                var mergeOperation = TableOperation.Merge(entity);
                var tableResult = await table.ExecuteAsync(mergeOperation);
                var resultUpdate= tableResult.HttpStatusCode; // returns 204
            }
        }
```

Now my readFunction queries table storage to get next job and then calls this function above.
which sets for the first time from ready to completed. however the next time it goes to readFunction again it pick up the same record with original state and causes a repeat of the process.

Why?

Update screen shot
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Once the process goes through the second function the process goes into Completed and once it hits the first one it the data get updated back to in processing
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjFDO.png

Update 2:

While using `Table.Replace` option instead of `Table.Merge`, the data started to update but half of the data was missing (null values)

Comment: Could you please provide the screenshot of table data?

Comment: According to my understanding, you want to update one row's data. After doing that, the row has old data and new data. Right?

Comment: @JimXu I have added the picture, to show the data. To your second comment, that is correct. To me it looks like there is a cache of data or reference to old data that gets flushed in.

Comment: If you want to update one row's data and move unneeded data, you can use the replace method : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/update-entity2 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/merge-entity

Answer (score 0):

The issue was quite simple the data has been stored but not replicated through out in time for me to read them.

Adding a delay has resolved the issue